# discordjs bot every time it is added to a server it has a reset

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Every time the bot is added to a new server, it resets. It starts all over again, so if a server is playing a song, it stops because it has been restarted.

ready.js

```js
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = async (client, servers) => {
    // Clients
    // When the client is ready, run this code
    client.once("ready", async () => {
        console.log("Ready!");

        fs.readFile("./db/serverList.json", "utf-8", async (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Erro ao ler o arquivo db servidores e inserir na variável: " + error);
            } else {
                const obj = await JSON.parse(data);

                for (let i = 0; i < obj.servers.length; i++) {
                    servers[i] = {
                        name: "asdas",
                    };
                }
            }
        });
    });
};
```

I don't know if I have to post some code related to this, if you want something ask me to edit it

Comment: Does it crash? What information appears on the console

Comment: this is the ready event.  do you have a guildCreate event handler?  do you have console output?